Conjecture: If $a\le b$ are any two opposite sides of a cyclic quadrilateral and $p \le q$ are the diagonals then $bp-aq \le \pi R^2-\frac{R^2}{16}$?
Let $a \le b$ be any two opposite sides of a cyclic quadrilateral in a circle of radius $R$ and let $p \le q$ be the diagonals ; then,
$$
0 \le bp - aq < \pi R^2 - \frac{R^2}{16}.
$$
The inequality on the LHS can be proved using Ptolemy's second theorem. The inequality on the RHS is a conjecture based on experimental data. I am looking for a proof or disproof of the conjecture.
Update: The answer below proves that
$$
0 \le bp - aq < \frac{16R^2}{3\sqrt{3}}
$$

What is context?

@Sahaj The context is found in the numerous questions Nilotpal Sinha has been asking in the recent times about quadrilaterals.

That's not context for this question. We wouldn't accept an arbitrary internet link as context, saying "go look at OP's other questions" is the same thing.

First part ("discovery") :
Your issue amounts to prove that
$$(bp - aq) \ < \ (\pi  - \frac{1}{16})\tag{1}$$
(indeed, by homogeneity, one can assume WLOG that the vertices of the quadrilateral are on the unit circle).
I have myself done an extended simulation (probably in the same spirit as yours), indicating that your conjecture looks true (but we will see in Part 2 that it isn't very exactly the case). Here is for example the histogram of the values of the difference between the RHS and the LHS of (1)
$$d=(\pi - \frac{1}{16})-(bp - aq).\tag{2}$$
for a million of random cases :

Observations :

apparently, no negative value !

the ratio of cases where $d$ is small is rather tiny ; otherwise said, inequality (1) is not tight in general.

a "smooth" histogram (is there an underlying tractable probability distribution ?).



Second part (obtaining a counterexample) :
A detailed analysis of the cases where inequality (1) very tight has led me to the following (limit/degenerated) case where :

two vertices, let us call them $C$ and $D$, "coalesce"  i.e., give a triangle $ABC$ instead of a quadrilateral $ABCD$.

and this triangle is isosceles with main vertex in $C$.


Let us analyse this case where $a=CD=0$,  $AB=b$, $CA=CB=p=q$.
Let $\alpha:=\angle(ABC)=\angle(BAC)$.
In this case, (1) is reduced to
$$bp < \pi - \frac{1}{16}\tag{3}$$
The sine law gives
$$\dfrac{p}{\sin(\alpha)}=\dfrac{b}{\sin(\pi-2\alpha)}=2$$
From there :
$$\begin{cases}p&=&2\sin(\alpha) \\ b&=&2 \sin(2 \alpha)\end{cases} \implies bp=\underbrace{4\sin(\alpha)\sin(2 \alpha)}_{f(\alpha)}$$
It remains to study the function :
$$f(\alpha):=8 \sin^2(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)=8 (1-\cos^2(\alpha))\cos(\alpha)\tag{4}$$
An extremal value of $f(\alpha)$ -which is readily verified as a maximum) is $$\frac{16}{3 \sqrt{3}}\approx 3.079201...\tag{5}$$
This maximum is obtained when $$\alpha=\cos^{-1}\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\tag{6}$$
(see appendix below for the proofs of (5) and (6)).
But :
$$\pi-\frac{1}{16} \approx 3.0790926...$$
which is very slightly less than the value of (5) : it has to be replaced by (5).
But it remains to prove that the value of (5) is indeed the good lower bound (with a $\le$ symbol instead of a $<$ symbol).
Appendix : Proof of formulas (5) and (6).
Setting $c:=\cos \alpha$ in $f(\alpha)$, it is equivalent to work on $\varphi(c):=8(1-c^2)c$. Its derivative is $\varphi'(c)=8(1-3c^2)$ which is zero for $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, which gives (6).
Plugging this value (6) in (4) gives the value (5).

Once more, the downvoting frenze ! What is wrong in my answer ? I have solved the question by showing that the upper bound $\pi - \frac{1}{16}$ isn't the best one by exhibiting a counterexample.

I am baffled why would anyone downvote this answer? Since it is non-trivial to downvote a valid answer, could the downvoters care to explain whats they thought was wrong with the answer?

The site doesn't promote problem statement questions. I personally disagree with this policy, but I believe that is what is driving people to downvote the question (which is of PSQ format) and this answer. I didn't downvote any.

COMMENT.- @Jean Marie: (Salut, mon ami).  I put the first upvote to this question and probably you have been who put the second one (I remembered what I heard a great mathematician say a long time ago: “An inequality is worth more than a hundred equalities.” (I didn't believe him but later I did).  Here my solution to this problem.
We have $$bp-aq=\dfrac{2}{\sin(\alpha)}\left(\text {área of } \triangle{PRQ}\setminus \text {area of } \triangle{PSQ}\right)\le\dfrac{2}{\sin(\alpha)}\text {área of } \triangle{PRQ}$$
In other words, $bp-aq$ is equal to the difference of the major area minus the minor area this difference multiplied by a common factor so the final bound  $\mathcal A=\dfrac{2}{\sin(\alpha)}\text {área of } \triangle{PRQ}$.
What is the max of  $\mathcal A$?  All cyclic quadrilateral is the unión of two triangles one of greater or equal area than the other. Then, keeping into account that the equilateral triangle has maximal área as inscribed in a circle, we have a bound for the major triangle in each cyclic quadrilateral.
It is elementary known (or easily calculated) that the área of an inscribed equilateral triangle is equal to $\Delta=\dfrac{3\sqrt3R^2}{4}$ and this fact (it being linear function of $R^2$) leads to the proof or a counterexample. In fact, this leads to the proof. We have as maximun value of $\mathcal A$
$$\mathcal A_{max}=\dfrac{2}{\sin(60^{\circ)}}\times \dfrac{3\sqrt3R^2}{4}=\frac{4}{\sqrt3}\times\dfrac{3\sqrt3R^2}{4}=3R^2$$
We are done because simplifying $R^2$
$$3\le\pi-\frac{1}{16}\iff3+\frac{1}{16}=3.0625\le \pi$$


1/ Can you explain your first line? I believe that division symbol should be a negative sign instead.  And if you're dividing, how can you just drop out that term (like if the area is very small)?  $\quad$ 2/ How does Jean's counterexample apply to your case? $\quad$ 3/ Even if we wanted to maximize $2 Area / \sin \alpha$, you cannot just maximize the area while ignoring $ \sin \alpha$. In fact, $ 2 Area / \sin \alpha  = bq \leq 4 R^2$, with equality in the limiting case of the triangle being a diameter.

@Calvin Lin: I am tired now, dear friend, I am 86 years old and I worked much to solve a problem with no answer altough not difficcult really. I respond you later (if I am not wrong as several times).
